# I've been all around Greece's paradise?

Tags: riddle, video-games

My pieces are associated with earth, sea and sky, dark, and time.

My adornments come from a source of etymology: a vessel, a mother, a mentor, and a power-hungry traitor.

The vessel, the dark, and a foul mouth point the way to where I'm useful.

What am I?

---

Hint 1:

> The woman who collects me is named after a month and a man.

Hint 2:

> The Greek paradise is opposed to Iron Man's world?

Hint 3:

> The game where I appear has been ranked among the best adventures, and it's self-proclaimed to have the greatest duration or distance (depending on interpretation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> The Stone Disk, from *The Longest Journey*, a game I haven't played in a looooong time

The Title "I've been all around Greece's paradise?" and hint 2:

> "Greece's paradise" is Arcadia (the game's alternate world of magic) and "Iron Man's world" is Stark (the game's name for our world in the future).  (Also, "around" was a clumsy hint at the object's shape.)

My pieces are associated with earth, sea and sky, dark, and time.

> This refers from whom you obtain the pieces:
>  Earth: The Banda (diggers).
>  Sea and sky: A piece that was further split between the Maerum (mermaid-like creatures) and the Alatien (winged creatures).
>  Dark: The Dark People.
>  Time: The [Venar](http://tlj.wikia.com/wiki/Venar) exist "outside of time".

My adornments come from a source of etymology: a vessel, a mother, a mentor, and a power-hungry traitor.

> Refers to the jewels.
>
>  In game, the etymology is that "Draic Kin" (the "correct" term for these beings) is the origin of the word "dragon".
>
>  Red -> Cortez -> Mentor
>  White -> Mother
>  Green -> Jacob McAllen -> Power-hungry
>  Blue -> Old God -> Vessel: Part of the game's lore is that the ancestors of the Maerum and the Alatien travelled to the precursor to Stark+Arcadia inside the Old God.

The vessel, the dark, and a foul mouth point the way to where I'm useful.

> This refers to characters that guide you.  The Old God instructs the Dark People to give the protagonist a star chart pointing the way to the entrance to the Guardian's Realm, which they originally made based on his supernatural communications.  Then, the map is deciphered by Burns Flipper, a hacker who swears a lot (and as the answerer remembered, he uses a hover chair):  "I remember a guy who looked like he was in a wheelchair or something (maybe just sat around a lot) who was vulgar...one of the first f-bombs I remember hearing in my life was an improvised middle name for the protagonist..."

Hint 3 is obviously:

> A hint as to the name (and adventure game genre) of the game.

---

I must say,

> I haven't played this game since I was a kid, so a bit (a lot) of research had to be done. But when your hint mentioned a female protagonist, I eventually thought of April Ryan...an oddly memorable name, I guess (also fits hint 1!).

Comment: This is correct - I think I'll edit it a bit to add some of the explanations for the clues, then accept it.